# how to set custom zoom in zoom out buttons on map v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to set own zoom in and zoom out buttons on google map v2 .I saw many examples but i did  not get any satisfied answer . If you know please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried some code?If you have you can post it here so that you get any help.

Comment: @Badrul i tried that was not working . if you know plz help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check it it will work on custom button.

```
 case R.id.zoomButton:
         mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
         break; 
 case R.id.unzoomButton:
         mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
         break;
```