# Customize android map v2 zoom in and out

Tags: android, dictionary, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2

In my android application i have used android map v2, i want to customize map zoom in and out as like below screen shot

[image]

can anyone suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321991/how-to-set-custom-zoom-in-zoom-out-buttons-on-map-v2-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321991/how-to-set-custom-zoom-in-zoom-out-buttons-on-map-v2-in-android)

Comment: Take vertical seekbar for this and then on moving the thumb update the Zoom value.

Comment: You can make your custom layout. Use `RelativeLayout` as a parent layout in which your google map and your custom buttons there.